# Javascript Regex to break classes/ID in LESS

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a problem in LESS wherein I have to separate the classes present in the LESS file.

For example, I have a class like:

```
mango{
  color:@color;
  li{
     color:red;
  }
}

#big-circle{
  color:green;
  li{
    color:@color;
  }
  a{
    color:red;
  }
  #majlis{
    background:blue;
  }
}
```

I have used the following regex to split the file into subclasses mango and #big-circle first. So I used the following regex: `/[\}]*[\}]/gm`. However, while it works for the first case, it fails for the second case.

Can anyone suggest me how can I modify my regex, if possible? Or should I look into some different method?

The output of the above code (as in the names of the classes):

```
#big-circle
a
#majlis
mango
```

While I need to break it into `big-circle` and `mango` only.

Comment: Since there is no technical difference between `mango{` and `a{` - both are letters followed by a curly brace - you will need a list of HTML elements `(a|abbr|b|...)` so that you can exclude them from the match. Also, `#big-circle` is an ID, not a class.

Comment: @Tomalak, a simple list of elements won't be of much use. LESS hierarchies can be complex: a class may have inside it another class, or an ID, or a tag. Further, mango is even not an HTML element, but a LESS compiler treats it as one.

Comment: Do not parse LESS or any other language with regexp. You will never get it right. Regexp does not have the theoretical parsing power to parse languages with the complexity of LESS. Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `/(\{[^\{\}]*\})/gm` to strip everything wrapped inside curly braces. By executing this regex recursively on filtered output you can extract the top level selectors.

```js
function extractTopLevelClasses (string) {
   var re = new RegExp(/(\{[^\{\}]*\})/gm);
   var recursiveStrip = function  (string) {
       var result = string.replace(re, ' ');
       if (result.indexOf('{') !== -1) {
           result = recursiveStrip(result);
       }

       return result;
   };

   var strippedString = recursiveStrip(string);
   var topLevelClasses = strippedString.trim().replace(' ',', ');

   return topLevelClasses;
}


var less = document.getElementById('less-content').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = extractTopLevelClasses(less);
```

```html
<pre id="less-content">
mango{
  color:@color;
  li{
     color:red;
  }
}

#big-circle{
  color:green;
  li{
    color:@color;
  }
  a{
    color:red;
  }
  #majlis{
    background:blue;
  }
}
</pre>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there was any means by which I can extract the class definiton as well using regexes. For example, like, obtaining the
`
#big-circle{
  color:green;
  li{
    color:@color;
  }
  a{
    color:red;
  }
  #majlis{
    background:blue;
  }
}`
information corresponding to these classes as well?